# Adding a different 'url' colum in Sharepoint Search results

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, ssp

I have a customised Sharepoint results xsl, and I've added new columns before (via Metadata mappings etc), this one has me stumped.
We have a document type, that can either be a 'Document' or a 'Link to a document'.
When I search I want to check the URL **INSIDE** the 'Link to a document' (what it points to), but I only get the actual URL for the 'Link to a document'.

What property do I need to be indexing to display this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking for a feature that dynamically indexes the contents of the 'Link to a document' URL. If true, unfortunately this can't be done with out-of-the-box SharePoint. The product only indexes a set list of URLs / content sources as specified in Search Admin.

As a custom solution, you could write your own indexer using a timer job that regularly extracts the contents of each 'Link to a document' URL column and stuffs it into a field in your document content type. Perhaps there is even a way to run SharePoint's indexer over it and use the results of that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I like the indexer idea too, however business needs must so an alternative route was created instead. Thanks